# Oracle service for Eris

Tags: oracles, eris-industries

In Ethereum, a smart contract can get external datafeed via oracle services. Does Eris also support such oracle services?

Comment: What do you mean by _orcacle services that ethereum provides_?

Answer (score 4):

Marco from Oraclize :)

<s>Currently, Oraclize doesn't support Eris. We are exploring a possible integration, and if there is demand from the community we will follow.So please, write us via email or contact us on our [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api) if you are interested</s>

We are now supporting Eris through our eris-bridge at an experimental stage. The code and the instructions are available [here](https://github.com/oraclize/eris-bridge). We support both Eris 0.12 and 0.14.

If you have any questions or you need help with setting it up feel free to ask help on our [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api)

Answer (score 3):

Edmund Edgar from [Reality Keys](https://www.realitykeys.com/developers/resources#ethereum) here.

Reality Keys posts signed data off-chain and you (or a process owned by one of your users) fetch it yourself from our website and send it to your chain. Doing it this way means we don't need the ability to access your blockchain, or indeed need to know that your blockchain exists. This works great with Eris.